# How to set an image according to string sent using i.putExtra?

Tags: android, image, android-intent, imageview

I want to have an image sent from recipe_button_list.java to recipe_display_screen.java,
and my current code highlights an error in my code...

This is how image is being sent in recipe_button_list:

```
Intent i= new Intent(getBaseContext(),recipedisplayscreen.class);
            //Sending data to the next screen
            i.putExtra("textView1", inputIngredients1.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("textView2", inputMethod1.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("image_string",R.drawable.blustudios);

            Log.e("n", inputMethod1.getText()+"."+ inputIngredients1.getText());
```

This is how image is recieved in recipe_display_screen:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
    String Ingredients = i.getStringExtra("textView1");
    String Method = i.getStringExtra("textView2");
    String RecipeImage = i.getStringExtra("image_string");
```

And this is how it is set (gives error(highlights setImageResource)

```
        MethodDisplay.setText(Method);
    IngredientsDisplay.setText(Ingredients);
    RecipeDisplay.setImageResource(RecipeImage);
```

What is my error???

Thanks in advance :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.drawable.blustudios` is not a `String`. The auto-generated `R.java` class contains integers which are actually resource ids.

Change this line...

```
String RecipeImage = i.getStringExtra("image_string");
```

...to this...

```
int RecipeImage = i.getIntExtra("image_string", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't send image as string.
You can either use `Serialized` or `Parcable`.

I know bitmap is already parcable, maybe ImageView is parcable too check it out.
In case it's not, just save the ImageView as a bitmap and send it.

Whatever the case use setParcableExtra() and same with get.

You clearly don't understand the concept of passing data between activites.
Check out [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android) question, you will probably figure out the answer from there.

Comment: hmmm still highlights RecipeDisplay.setBackgroundResource(RecipeImage); (?)

Comment: Edited the answer, check out the link.